# How can i simulate a button click in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a button

```
    <button className="btn btn-primary col-md-2"  onClick={loaddetails} >Details</button>
```

How can i programatically do a button click without actually clicking on the button ?

Comment: Uuuh... Why do you just call loaddetails() somewhere in your code if you want to simulate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the loaddeatils() where you want to execute the button simulation.  If the question is far trickier than that, then please add more details to the question. Thanks.

================================

Updated answer to the question update

```
//Parent Component
function Parent = () => {
    const buttonClick = () => { console.log("Test"); }
    return <Child customFunction={buttonClick} />
}

//Child Component
function Child = ({buttonClick}) => {
    const [dependant, setDependant] = useState();
    useEffect(()=>{
    buttonClick();
    },[dependant])
}
```

if you pass the dependant as empty list then it would run on the initial render.

Comment: well i come from another component and set a value in usestate , but the value isnt set yet until the next render . But if i do a load details its fine , because the user details id input box is populated

Comment: its as if the new value hasnt been updated until the next render. So can i simulate a button click ?

Comment: When you say you come from another component is it a parent component? if yes have you tried passing the function as a prop and call it within the child component. if no can you draw the picture more clearly.

Comment: no I havent how can i pass the function as a prop, is there a link of an example

Comment: if this answers your question please mark it as the answer @Luci